Value_counts printing wrong value - adds column name as index
While working a pandas value_counts exercise, the return is never what is expected and what I need to get
The code I used is:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
value_counts = df['a'].value_counts(dropna=True, sort=True)
print(value_counts)

The problem is that the code should be printing:
2    3
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64

But instead its printing:
a
2    3
1    2
Name: count, dtype: int64

Is there any explanation why? I'm using Jupyter if it helps. Thanks

What's your version of Pandas and can you double check if the exercise is as simple as the example you provide?

This is expected, value_counts has been setting the column name as index name in the recent pandas versions.
The output was different in previous versions:
# pandas 1.5.3
2    3
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64

# pandas 2.1.4
a
2    3
1    2
Name: count, dtype: int64

To remove this name you can rename before value_counts:
df['a'].rename().value_counts(dropna=True, sort=True)

Or rename_axis after:
df['a'].value_counts(dropna=True, sort=True).rename_axis(None)

Output:
2    3
1    2
Name: count, dtype: int64


@Wayne that's a good suggestion, you should feel free to edit the question to improve the title. SO is collaborative by nature (see the help page on editing) ;)

You're code seems to work or provide the output that you want.I have tested it in my jupyter notebook.Please check other part of your code that might causing it? or restart your jupyter environment

Thats weird, I've tried with Spyder, Jupyter, even a random online compiler and it always prints the same

The line creating a series object,and taking "a" as index.You could either add .reset_index() to reset indices or if you only want to remove the index name then you could do something bellow :
value_counts = df['a'].value_counts( dropna=True,sort=True)  then
value_counts.index.name=None
